# Chinese characters are question marks in .dta file

Tags: stata

I have .dta file that contains Chinese characters. Opening the dataset with

```
use "dataset path"
```

result in question marks:

[image]

Is there anyway I can change the encoding while reading the .dta file?

P.S. my stata is updated.

Comment: You can try exporting your .dta file as a .csv using `export delimited` and then re-importing the .csv into Stata using `import delimited myfile.csv, encoding(GBK)`. Some Googling suggests that Chinese characters are also often encoded as UTF-8, so you could try that instead of GBK. Check `help import delimited` for other possible encodings.